# Regular expression for check specific 3 characters present in the string

Tags: python, regex

I need to check whether a pattern is date format or not. patterns be like
ddmmyyyy, dd-mm-yyyy, dd_mmm_yyyy, yyyy-mm-dd, mm/dd/yyyy...

How to check the string contains d,m,y present or not. I tried the following way but it is only working for ddmmyyyy format. If there any special characters it's not working

```
pattern='Anyfile_<dd_mm_yyyy>.zip'
result = re.search("<([dmy]{8,})>", pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if result:
    print('hello')
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: with three distinct formats, you may find you want three distinct checks!

Comment: Your pattern doesn't allow separator characters `-` and `_`.

Comment: @Barmar yes it's not allowing. Is there any way?

Comment: Is it on purpose that the third pattern has three `m`?

Comment: @itprorh66  tried code is already there but it's not working if there any special character between the characters

Comment: @trincot yes dates like 02may2021. I just want to search weather a string contains d,m,y present or not

Comment: What is the "..."? Can you provide a complete list of the formats you want to support?

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern just matches any mixture of the letters `d`, `m`, and `y`. It doesn't match the separator characters, it doesn't require the letters to be paired like `dd`, and it doesn't require them to be in a specific order.

```
result = re.search(r"<(dd([-_]?))m{2,3}\2y{4})>", pattern, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

This matches `dd` followed by an optional separator, the separator is either `-` or `_`. The separator is captured so we can refer to it later.

Then it matches `mm` or `mmm`.

Then it uses the back-reference `\2` to match the same separator as earlier.

Then it matches `yyyy`.

Comment: what if the pattern like mmddyyyy or yyyymmdd so i just want to search whether a string contains d, m, y without considering order

Comment: That's not one of the patterns you mentioned in the question.

Comment: Yeah sorry I am facing such scenarios too

Comment: I'm not sure a regexp is the appropriate tool if you need to be more general than this.